# Netbeans: Java Application with NullPointerExceptions when running outside of Netbeans

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, netbeans-8

I am relatively new to Java programming, I have been using C# for the past 10 years as my main language.  I do work on a Java application every now and then to just add localization to it.  This is where I stumbled upon this NullPointerException.

When I build the java app in Netbeans and run it from there, everything works perfectly fine.  When I deploy it to our local server, I am getting the nullpointer.  This leads me to believe that something is not being deployed with the application when it is built.

Looking into the error log, I am not seeing anything that is helpful in finding the line number the null value is coming from.  Here is a view of the log:

```
Dec 22, 2017 7:18:34 AM removedcompanyname.appname.b.i a
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at removedcompanyname.appname.f.a(Unknown Source)
    at removedcompanyname.appname.f.a(Unknown Source)
    at removedcompanyname.appname.b.n(Unknown Source)
    at removedcompanyname.appname.b.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at removedcompanyname.appname.b.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at removedcompanyname.appname.Main$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have been searching for what to do to see the line numbers, but I have not found anything that has been helped.  Any ideas what I can do to find the null value?

Thanks.

Comment: Those names f.a and b.n --- did you put them there? Otherwise it seems that your setup is somehow obfuscating the generated java byte code. I would start by disabling that.

Comment: @GhostCat - I did not put those there.  I will look at disabling the obfuscating, but I think that is something that the original Dev were told to do to limit the size of the files.

Comment: It basically kills your ability to read stack traces. What do you consider more important at this point in time - your ability to debug your problems, or the size of files ... that contain bugs, unless you are able to debug them?

Comment: I completely agree.  I just meant i have to find out why we have that need and check with the owner of the app.

Comment: @GhostCat - Thank you for the help.  I was able to see the line numbers after disabling the obfuscation.  This was killing me.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are very welcome. I am glad that my small contribution enabled you to solve your problem. And in case you want to practice upvoting, now that you reached that level ... feel free to visit my profile ;-)